# Is put-ing to a ByteBuffer then writing it to a file more efficient than writing the individual field

Tags: java, java-io, bytebuffer

I want to write **ONLY** the values of the data members of an object into a file, so here I can can't use **serialization** since it writes a whole lot other information which i don't need. Here's is what I have implemented in two ways. One using byte buffer and other without using it.

Without using ByteBuffer:
**1st method**

```
public class DemoSecond {

    byte characterData;
    byte shortData;
    byte[] integerData;
    byte[] stringData;

    public DemoSecond(byte characterData, byte shortData, byte[] integerData,
        byte[] stringData) {
        super();
        this.characterData = characterData;
        this.shortData = shortData;
        this.integerData = integerData;
        this.stringData = stringData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoSecond dClass= new DemoSecond((byte)'c', (byte)0x7, new byte[]{3,4},
            new byte[]{(byte)'p',(byte)'e',(byte)'n'});

        File checking= new File("c:/objectByteArray.dat");
        try {
            if (!checking.exists()) {
                checking.createNewFile();
            }
            // POINT A
            FileOutputStream bo = new FileOutputStream(checking);
            bo.write(dClass.characterData);
            bo.write(dClass.shortData);
            bo.write(dClass.integerData);
            bo.write(dClass.stringData);
            // POINT B
            bo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("FNF");
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOE");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using byte buffer: One more thing is that the size of the data members will always remain fixed i.e. characterData= 1byte, shortData= 1byte, integerData= 2byte and stringData= 3byte. So the total size of this class is 7byte **ALWAYS**

**2nd method**

```
            // POINT A
            FileOutputStream bo = new FileOutputStream(checking);
            ByteBuffer buff= ByteBuffer.allocate(7);
            buff.put(dClass.characterData);
            buff.put(dClass.shortData);
            buff.put(dClass.integerData);
            buff.put(dClass.stringData);
            bo.write(buff.array());
            // POINT B
```

I want know which one of the two methods is more optimized? And kindly give the reason also.

The above class **DemoSecond** is just a sample class.

My original classes will be of **size 5 to 50 bytes**. I don't think here size might be the issue.
But each of my classes is of fixed size like the **DemoSecond**

**Also there are so many files of this type which I am going to write in the binary file.**

**PS**

if I use serialization it also writes the word "characterData", "shortData", "integerData","stringData" also and other information which I don't want to write in the file. What I am corcern here is about **THEIR VALUES ONLY**. In case of this example its:**'c', 7, 3,4'p','e','n'**. I want to write only this 7bytes into the file, NOT the other informations which is USELESS to me.

Comment: Why don't you declare the `transient` all the unnecessary parts?

Comment: if I use serialization it also writes the word "characterData", "shortData", "integerData","stringData" also. What I am corcern here is about the values only. In case of this example its: 'c', 7, 3,4'p','e','n'

Comment: why don't you put some timings into your code and test it out with a million objects.  My guess would be a non buffered output stream would be quickest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are doing file I/O, you should bear in mind that the I/O operations are likely to be very much slower than any work done by the CPU in your output code. To a first approximation, the cost of I/O is an amount proportional to the amount of data you are writing, plus a fixed cost for each operating system call made to do the I/O.

So in your case you want to minimise the number of operating system calls to do the writing. This is done by buffering data in the application, so the application performs few put larger operating system calls.

Using a byte buffer, as you have done, is one way of doing this, so your `ByteBuffer` code will be more efficient than your `FileOutputStream` code.

But there are other considerations. Your example is not performing many writes. So it is likely to be very fast anyway. Any optimisation is likely to be a premature optimisation. Optimisations tend to make code more complicated and harder to understand. To understand your `ByteBuffer` code a reader needs to understand how a `ByteBuffer` works *in addition* to everything they need to understand for the `FileOutputStream` code. And if you ever change the file format, you are more likely to introduce a bug with the `ByteBuffer` code (for example, by having a too small a buffer).

Buffering of output is commonly done. So it should not surprise you that Java already provides code to help you. That code will have been written by experts,  tested and debugged. Unless you have special requirements you should always use such code rather than writing your own. The code I am referring to is the `BufferedOutputStream` class.

To use it simply adapt your code that does not use the `ByteBuffer`, by changing the line of your code that opens the file to

```
 OutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(checking));
```

Comment: Agreed on the BufferedOutputStream for problems like this. Buffering the writes are where most of the performance benefits will come from. I might also use a DataOutputStream as the last stream in the chain.

Comment: if i use **OutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(checking));** then the execution time is less in the 1st method(without byte buffer), are you saying that I should use the 2nd method with the OutputStream?

Comment: @kaze No, do not use the `BYteBuffer` at all

Comment: like this OutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(checking));
bo.write(dClass.characterData);
bo.write(dClass.shortData);
bo.write(dClass.integerData);
bo.write(dClass.stringData);

Answer (score 0):

The two methods differ only in the byte buffer allocated.

If you are concerning about unnecessary write action to file, there is already a `BufferedOutputStream` you can use, for which buffer is allocated internally, and if you are writing to same outputstream multiple times, it is definitely more efficient than allocating buffer every time manually.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simplest to use a DataOutputStream around a BufferedOutputStream around the FileOutputStream.

NB You can't squeeze 'shortData' into a byte. Use the various primitives of DataOutputStream, and use the corresponding ones of DataInputStream when reading them back.

Comment: The above class **DemoSecond** is just a sample class. Even if short has a size 2 bytes, I am going to convert it into 2 bytes and then write that two byte separately one after the other. eg. short a= 1282 (1010000010), so my two bytes will be 5,2

Comment: All the more reason to use DataOutputStream to do all that for you.